# C compiler cannot create executables - Cygwin/MiniGW

Tags: gcc, cygwin, mingw, portaudio, pyaudio

I'm trying to compile [Pyaudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/), (a Python module) from source, since I'm using Windows, and only 32-bit binaries are available - I need 64. Following [these instructions](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/compilation.html) I downloaded Cygwin, and installed every component, to be safe. Installing Portaudio, another module, is required first.

When I run `CFLAGS="-mno-cygwin" LDFLAGS="-mno-cygwin" ./configure`, I get the error `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables. See 'config.log' for more details.` config.log has an additional line below that message: `gcc: The -mno-cygwin flag has been removed; use a mingw-targeted cross-compiler.`

This leads me to believe that perhaps Cygwin is using the wrong compiler; the instructions are for using MinGw with Cygwin, but I never specified minigw in the process. I also wonder if there's something in the PyAudio build files that needs to be changed for 64-bit. I know nothing about C, compiling, Cygwin or MinGW, and am new to programming in general. Any ideas? Any other information I can provide?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Current versions of Cygwin `gcc` do not support `-mno-cygwin` anymore because it never really worked correctly.  Instead, you should use a proper cross-compiler, which is provided by the `mingw64-i686-gcc` packages, then run `./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32`.

Comment: Another option instead of cross compiling from the Cygwin environment is to use a native windows MinGW installation (TDM or nuwen distros are very easy to install) and use MinGW's MSYS environment to handle the `./configure` step. I assume that Pyaudio's configure step would work in MSYS.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer solved the problem I posted. I ran into other problems later in the 'python setup.py build --static-link -cmingw32' step, out of the Cygwin environment. The error was 'cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin', error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1'. When trying without -cming32, the error changed to 'Unable to find vcvarsall.bat'. I ended up finding a binary at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ that allowed me to stop  troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it is an antivirus that is causing problems.
I had avast and had to disable it.